# Powershell Where-Object returning unmatched values

Tags: powershell, where-object

I have a hash table of PSObjects that holds information about widnows patches and CVE numbers, it takes the format:

```
ID                  : 2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate : 13/09/2022 07:00:00
CvrfUrl             : https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
Severity            :
DocumentTitle       : September 2022 Security Updates
cve                 : CVE-2022-37969
Alias               : 2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  : 04/10/2022 07:00:00
```

I am trying to extract the record that has a matching CVE. I thought his should work:

```
$results | where {$results.cve -eq 'CVE-2022-38006'}
```

but it returns a number of records (including the correct one) but for most the `$records.cve` element has absolutely nothing in common with the requested filter and I wouldn't expect it to be returned.

```
ID                  : 2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate : 13/09/2022 07:00:00
CvrfUrl             : https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
Severity            :
DocumentTitle       : September 2022 Security Updates
cve                 : CVE-2022-37969
Alias               : 2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  : 04/10/2022 07:00:00

ID                  : 2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate : 13/09/2022 07:00:00
CvrfUrl             : https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
Severity            :
DocumentTitle       : September 2022 Security Updates
cve                 : CVE-2022-38004
Alias               : 2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  : 04/10/2022 07:00:00

ID                  : 2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate : 13/09/2022 07:00:00
CvrfUrl             : https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
Severity            :
DocumentTitle       : September 2022 Security Updates
cve                 : CVE-2022-38005
Alias               : 2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  : 04/10/2022 07:00:00

ID                  : 2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate : 13/09/2022 07:00:00
CvrfUrl             : https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
Severity            :
DocumentTitle       : September 2022 Security Updates
cve                 : CVE-2022-38006
Alias               : 2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  : 04/10/2022 07:00:00
```

Get-Member says the CVE element is a string:

```
PS E:\Scripts\Ian\GIT\XDR> $results | gm

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                MemberType   Definition
----                ----------   ----------
Equals              Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType             Method       type GetType()
ToString            Method       string ToString()
Alias               NoteProperty string Alias=2022-Sep
CurrentReleaseDate  NoteProperty string CurrentReleaseDate=04/10/2022 07:00:00
cve                 NoteProperty string cve=
CvrfUrl             NoteProperty string CvrfUrl=https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/cvrf/v2.0/document/2022-Sep
DocumentTitle       NoteProperty string DocumentTitle=September 2022 Security Updates
ID                  NoteProperty string ID=2022-Sep
InitialRealeaseDate NoteProperty string InitialRealeaseDate=13/09/2022 07:00:00
Severity            NoteProperty string Severity=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than:

```
$results | where {$results.cve -eq 'CVE-2022-38006'}
```

Try:

```
$results | where {$_.cve -eq 'CVE-2022-38006'}
```

Or more simply:

```
$results | where cve -eq 'CVE-2022-38006'
```

Comment: Thank you ... sometimes the simplest thing is what catches you out. Ive stared at that for hours this morning.

Comment: You can even drop the quotes.